# Refactoring a function to take an object instead of a single key:value pair as arguments in typescript

Tags: javascript, function, vue.js, arguments, vuejs3

I am working on a component for a friends icon library, but I am having troubles with their `set()` function.

The issue is, I have two functions I want to call, `setRandomColor()` and `setColor()`, they should both be updating two values in this `modelValue` computed prop. However the set function only takes one argument (the `prop` (key) name and the `value` of that prop(key) ) and is spreading the rest of the `props.modelValue` values in the emit function.

Since my two  `setRandomColor()` and `setColor()` are setting two values and each time the function is called, it's spreading the default `modelValue`, the first modelValue changed will be reverted.

I know this is a really simple question, but I am not able to figure out how to refactor this `set()` function to take a single OR multiple `key: value` pairs to update modelValue and emit it properly to it's parent component.

This should be a really quick fix, but I am having a total brainfart.

Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated.

**NOTE:**
My attempt to refactor the `set()` function is below this block of code.

**Component not working**

```
<script lang="ts" setup>
import { PropType, ref, defineComponent } from 'vue'
import DialogWrapper from '../components/DialogWrapper.vue'
import IconButton from './IconButton.vue'
import Stack from './Stack.vue'
import { getRandomColor, cssVar } from '../helpers/colorHelpers'
import { defaultsIconConfig, IconConfig } from '../types'
import Tooltip from './Tooltip.vue'
import { ColorPicker } from 'vue-color-kit'
import 'vue-color-kit/dist/vue-color-kit.css'

const props = defineProps({
  /**
   * @example 'type'
   */
  kind: {
    type: String as PropType<'type' | 'color' | 'stroke' | 'modelValueisDarkMode' | 'background'>,
    required: true,
  },
  /**
   * @type {{ name?: string, type: 'pop' | 'print', color: string, stroke: string} & { isDarkMode: boolean }}
   */
  modelValue: {
    type: Object as PropType<Partial<IconConfig> & { isDarkMode: boolean }>,
    default: () => ({ ...defaultsIconConfig({ isDarkMode: false }) }),
  },
  /**
   * @type {{ name?: string, type: 'pop' | 'print', color: string, stroke: string }}
   */
  configComputed: {
    type: Object as PropType<Partial<IconConfig>>,
    default: () => ({ ...defaultsIconConfig() }),
  },
})
const emit = defineEmits(['update:modelValue'])
function set(
  prop: 'type' | 'color' | 'stroke' | 'isDarkMode' | 'randomColor',
  value: string | boolean,
) {
  emit('update:modelValue', { ...props.modelValue, [prop]: value })
}

function setRandomColor() {
  const randomColor = getRandomColor()
  set('color', randomColor)
  set('randomColor', true)
}
function setColor(c: string) {
  set('color', c)
  set('randomColor', false)
}

const nightfall = cssVar('nightfall')
const moonlight = cssVar('moonlight')

function openColorPicker() {
  colorPickerIsVisible.value = true
}
let colorPickerIsVisible = ref(false)
function changeColor(color) {
  const alpha = ''
  const newValue = color.hex + alpha
  set('color', newValue)
}

const colorSelection = [
  cssVar('sig-purple'),
  cssVar('sig-green'),
  cssVar('sig-yellow'),
  cssVar('sig-blue'),
  cssVar('sig-pink'),
]
</script>

<script lang="ts">
export default defineComponent({
  inheritAttrs: false,
})
</script>

<template>
  <Stack v-if="kind === 'type'" v-bind="$attrs" class="picker" classes="justify-center">
    <Tooltip text="Print ❏">
      <IconButton
        :iconConfig="{
          name: 'can',
          type: 'print',
          color: modelValue.isDarkMode ? 'black' : modelValue.color,
          stroke: modelValue.isDarkMode ? modelValue.color : 'black',
        }"
        :backgroundColor="modelValue.isDarkMode ? moonlight : 'white'"
        :isActive="modelValue.type === 'print'"
        :activeColor="modelValue.color"
        animationClass="anime-shake"
        @click="set('type', 'print')"
      />
    </Tooltip>
    <Tooltip text="Pop!">
      <IconButton
        :iconConfig="{ ...modelValue, name: 'can', type: 'pop' }"
        :backgroundColor="modelValue.isDarkMode ? moonlight : 'white'"
        :isActive="modelValue.type === 'pop'"
        animationClass="anime-shake"
        @click="set('type', 'pop')"
      />
    </Tooltip>
  </Stack>
  <Stack v-if="kind === 'color'" v-bind="$attrs" class="picker" classes="justify-center">
    <IconButton
      v-for="c in colorSelection"
      :key="c"
      :iconConfig="{ color: modelValue.color }"
      :backgroundColor="c"
      :isActive="modelValue.color === c && modelValue.randomColor === false"
      @click="setColor(c)"
    />
    <IconButton
      :iconConfig="{ ...configComputed, name: 'color-picker' }"
      :backgroundColor="modelValue.isDarkMode ? moonlight : 'white'"
      :colorRing="true"
      @click="colorPickerIsVisible = true"
    />
    <IconButton
      :iconConfig="{ ...configComputed, name: 'refresh' }"
      :backgroundColor="modelValue.isDarkMode ? moonlight : 'white'"
      :colorRing="true"
      :isActive="modelValue.randomColor"
      @click="setRandomColor"
    />
  </Stack>
  <Stack v-if="kind === 'background'" v-bind="$attrs" class="picker" classes="justify-center">
    <IconButton
      backgroundColor="white"
      class="_background-picker thin-border--dark"
      :iconConfig="{ name: 'sun-filled', type: 'pop', color: 'black' }"
      @click="set('isDarkMode', false)"
    />
    <IconButton
      :backgroundColor="nightfall"
      class="_background-picker thin-border--light"
      :iconConfig="{ name: 'moon-filled', type: 'pop', color: 'white' }"
      @click="set('isDarkMode', true)"
    />
  </Stack>
  <Stack v-if="kind === 'stroke'" v-bind="$attrs" class="picker" classes="justify-center">
    <input type="color" @change="() => set('color', '#e2e2e2')" />
  </Stack>
  <DialogWrapper :isVisible="colorPickerIsVisible" @close="colorPickerIsVisible = false">
    <ColorPicker
      :theme="modelValue.isDarkMode === true ? 'dark' : 'light'"
      :color="modelValue.color"
      @changeColor="(val) => changeColor(val)"
    />
  </DialogWrapper>
</template>

<style lang="sass">
@import '../css/variables.sass'
.picker
  ._background-picker svg
    opacity: 0.1
.picker-tooltip
  font-size: 1.5em
  +pa($md)
  +C(background, primary)
  border-radius: $md
  font-weight: 500
  white-space: nowrap

.hu-color-picker
  .color-set
    justify-content: space-evenly
  .color-alpha
    display: none
</style>
```

This is my attempt to refactor the function, but when I'm spreading the array of objects from the `set()` argument, I'm still just getting two objects and am stuck from this point.

**Attempts to refactor the set() function**

```
function set(
  object: {
    prop: 'type' | 'color' | 'stroke' | 'isDarkMode' | 'randomColor'
    value: string | boolean
  }[],
) {
  console.log(`object → `, ...object)
  emit('update:modelValue', { ...props.modelValue, ...object })
}

function setRandomColor() {
  const randomColor = getRandomColor()
  set([
    { prop: 'color', value: randomColor },
    { prop: 'randomColor', value: true },
  ])
  // set('color', randomColor)
  // set('randomColor', true)
}
function setColor(c: string) {
  set([
    { prop: 'color', value: c },
    { prop: 'randomColor', value: false },
  ])
  // set('color', c)
  // set('randomColor', false)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want the set function to accept one OR more objects?

Add spread ”…” before the parameter. Sadly Im on my phone and snippet editor doesnt support touch devices.

function set(
… object: {
prop: 'type' | 'color' | 'stroke' | 'isDarkMode' | 'randomColor'
value: string | boolean
}[],
) {

More reading: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/c63ec5/use-of-params-in-typescript/

To handle the parameter objects I guess something like:

{ …props.modelValue, …object.reduce((acc, {prop, value}) => {…acc, [prop]: value}, {});

Comment: thank you for the response!

Yeah, basically I have a config object and I want to be able to `set()` one or more key:value pairs in the config object. I just don't know what to put in the second part of the `emit()` function. I spread the default `prop.modelValue`s, but then get lost on waht to do with the arguement object.

Comment: I did an update on my answer @LovelyAndy

Comment: Thanks for the update! For some reason I get the `No overload matches this call.`
The first part of it reads `Overload 1 of 3, '(callbackfn: (previousValue: { prop: "type" | "color" | "stroke" | "randomColor" | "isDarkMode"; value: string | boolean; }, currentValue: { prop: "type" | "color" | "stroke" | "randomColor" | "isDarkMode"; value: string | boolean; }, currentIndex: number, array: { ...; }[]) => { ...; }, initialValue: { ...; }): { ...; }', gave the following error`

Not sure how to fix this, bu reduce does make sense here I think!